# Google Analytics Day/Week reports not matching - SUM(DAYS) != WEEK

Tags: google, google-analytics, traffic, visitors

I'm having a hard time understanding non matching data in Google Analytics.

When I view unique visitors, and press the PER DAY resolution, I get a pretty steady picture:
[image]
Although, if I click the PER WEEK resolution, I get this sudden drop:
[image]
I've even checked the export option, and the SUM(DAYS) just doesn't add up to the WEEK stats. Does it calculate what is considered a 'unique' visitor differently according to time span(day/week)? Has anyone else seen such non-compatible patterns, or has any explanation that might shed light?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of Google. The more you dig the more issues you find. If this tells you anything it is that you can figure out patterns on google if data is 100%... So why would they do that. I made screen shots of traffic from 6 months ago, then the following month went back and somehow that traffic was reporting an increase of about 1000 visitors.

The important thing is you get a close enough report to know you are getting traffic, the true measure is in you keyword positions and conversions.